# Does MoveIt have python tutorial for kinematic and inverse kinematic solver?

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how to use IK and FK functionalities in python using MoveIt.

I am working on a baxter robot and I am sure I can use baxter's SDK and Moveit python API. But is there an easier way to do it within Move it itself? The forward kinematic tutorial is given on for C++ API's

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255047/does-moveit-have-python-tutorial-for-kinematic-and-inverse-kinematic-solver?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you start MoveIt for your robot, MoveIt provides an IK and FK service for your robot. All you have to do is call the respective service.

You can also use orocos kdl for IK and FK without MoveIt.

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1